# Hive Insert Overwrite partitioned table sending data to a single reducer

Tags: hive, mapreduce

I have a non-partitioned table SRC. I have a destination table DST partitioned a date field action_dt. I want to load data from SRC into DST and partition it by action_dt.

At the time of load, SRC table has data (30 Million records) for just one action_dt (example 20170701). I use the below query to do an insert:

```
SET mapred.max.split.size=268435456;
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET parquet.compression=SNAPPY;
SET hive.merge.size.per.task=268435456;
SET hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=268435456;
SET hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
SET hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb = 16384;
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx12g;

SET hive.execution.engine=tez;
SET hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=104857600;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE DST partition(action_dt)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, action_dt FROM SRC;
```

The SRC table is gzip compressed and has about 80 files of size 80-100MB. When the above query is executed, although around 70 reducer are launched, 69 reducers are executed within 10 seconds, but the 70th reducer is processing all the data.

Why is this happening? Is it because it is recognizing that the data belongs to one 'action_dt' (20170701)? Is there a way this can be split so that multiple reducers can process this data? I tried using DISTRIBUTE BY but did not work.

Appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have statistics gathered for table ? (i.e. do you run ANALYZE TABLE statement ?)

Comment: Remove the the `merge.mapfiles` property and you will have no reducer at all -- a simple INSERT-SELECT query on 80 non-splittable files _(assuming `TextFile` format + GZip)_ requires 80 mappers to generate 80 target files. Try with `EXPLAIN` command with and without the property...

Comment: Note that `avgsize` properties are used at compile time, and they are easily confused by size estimates derived from *compressed* file size...

Comment: @Shubhangi Yes I did try with the ANALYZE TABLE statement as well.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I removed the merge.mapfiles property. With the SRC table being Text + GZIP format, it still generated X number of reducers. I believe the reason could be that it is trying to 'reduce' all data related to the one action_dt value available in the SRC table. Does this make sense? I am still stuck with the problem for now.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the TEZ specific property `hive.merge.tezfiles` > set that one to `false`, or else switch `execution.engine` to legacy `mr`...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for your help. However, hive.merge.tezfiles is by default set to false. So, even that property does not make a difference. Any other thoughts? Have you seen this before?
 Could you try simulating such a scenario?

Comment: Your data size is 100M and `hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=104857600`  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45350927/2700344

Comment: @leftjoin Thanks for the feedback. The input data size is around 80 files of  size 80-100MB and are GZip compressed (text). All of this data is getting written into a single file by one reducer. By setting hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=104857600, I expected that the max file size output by any reducer is 100 MB. But I am getting a single 10GB+ file.

Comment: @user3031097 And hive.exec.reducers.max ?

Comment: @leftjoin We are not explicitly setting the hive.exec.reducers.max property. The default value being taken is 1009.

Comment: @user3031097 try to add `distribute by` some evenly distributed column, not partition